# How to set top div height to the remaining height css

Tags: html, css

I have a div **positioned fixed** at the bottom of the screen with **fixed height of 200px;** How can I set the div height on top of it **to the remaining height**?

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="wrap"></div>

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font: 18px "bonvenocf";
}

#wrap {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align:center;  
    background: #1b1b1b;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    background: #0084ff;
    min-height:320px;
}
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kLo0v9q/6/

Comment: try this? http://jsfiddle.net/8kLo0v9q/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the following codes:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will ensure the top div will take up the remaining space above the fixed bar

Comment: Thanks but how can I align #container content vertically?

Comment: You can use `display: table;` on the container and then `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on the content. I think that's what you're after

Answer (score 1):

Alter your `container` `div` to have `height: 100%`:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0084ff;
    min-height:320px;
}
```